# Can't get piped stream from child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

In parent.js

```
child = fork(filePath,[],{silent : true});
child.send({
        msgtype: "path",
        path: path,
        options: options,
      });
child.stdout.on("data",(data)=>{
     console.log(data);
})
```

in child process.js

```
let createQueue = require("queue-async");
let readdirp = require("readdirp");

process.on("message", function(msg) {
  let files = "";
  if (msg && msg.msgtype === "path") {
    let pathname = msg.path;
    files = readdirp(pathname);
    process.send({
      msg: "detials",
      details: msg
    });
    files.on("error", e => {
      process.send({
        msg: "killMe",
        details: null
      });
    });
    files.on("end", () => {
      process.send({
        msg: "killMe",
        details: null
      });
    });
    files.pipe(process.stdout)
  }
});
```

My problem i have no errors, and child process in not exit.

But `child.stdout.on("data")` is not triggered, i don't know what happens in background.

Why i can't get data from child ?? what am i missing, can anyone help please ??

Answer (score 2):

In `parent.js`, you should change `child.stdout.on` into `child.on` in order to receive what the child process is sending.

Also you should inverse the logic in `parent.js`

1. `child.on`
2. `child.send`

Please have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Comment: I found an another bug i run the child in terminal using node, it throws, The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. i found this related this,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458252/reading-objects-from-readable-stream-causes-typeerror-exception?rq=1

Comment: first i need to solve this, how to pipe object stream to stdout ?.